# How to use PHP to restore page with content

Tags: php, html, session, cookies

I am trying to build a web app like this using php, it has two pages:

**select.php** has some radio buttons in a html form for users to choose. and there is a submit button post the form to a confirmation page.

**confirm.php** echos the summery from previous page and there is a "back" button allow users to change their selections in the previous page.

In this point, when I hit the "back" button and previous page restored, I would like all my previous selections displayed. (more clearly, if I chose a radio button and submit in select.php, I want the radio button still being chose after I go back to select page by hitting "back" button from confirm.php page.)

Please give me some idea about how to do this kind of restore page thing.

Comment: Are your taking about the 'back' button from the browser? If you implemented your own back button on the page? in the last case just call the select.php with the parameters you received in the confirm.php. You could use also a PHP session. [PHP Session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Save your selection in **session**.
2. In `select.php` pre-select the radio buttons if its found in session.

BTW, You should not rely on back button of browser. Create you own back button on `confirm.php` page. This back button will go to `select.php` using no `history.back()`

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP-Protocol is stateless.
So when calling select.php the server doesn't know anything about your previous selection.

You can either save the selection in the session or in a cookie and restore in in selection.php